# ssh login using authorized_keys alone without privatekey or password

Tags: ssh, security

I am trying to understand `ssh` using `authorized_keys` alone (i.e. not using local private keys). This is what I have done so far.

1. Created a local public + private key using the usual `ssh-keygen -t rsa`.
2. Copied the public key to the `authorized_keys` in the remote machine.
3. I deleted the public and private key on local machine.

I am able to successfully login to the remote machine without any password or private keys. I am unable to figure out which public key is being offered or where the key exists.

I tried to understand how the authentication is happening in my case.

Here is the output of `ssh -v`.

```
(base) xxxx@r-23-105-25-172 XXXX Summer 2021 % ssh -v xxxxx@xxxx.xxx.xxx.xx
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/xxxx/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxxx.xxxx.edu.sg port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to xxxx.xxxx.edu.sg:22 as 'xxxx'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:GxTuRA57OBBU6fmXjFwVCSzfadJps3WqmvkPMulr+fo
debug1: Host 'xxxx.xxxx.edu.sg' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/xxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: xxxx@r-23-105-25-172.comp.xxxx.edu.sg RSA SHA256:01e48aRr8gQiUtaLrKj5O9qSmfadlMXHiTcbdzoS+LQ agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: xxxx@r-23-105-25-172.comp.xxxx.edu.sg RSA SHA256:01e48aRr8gQiUtaLrKj5O9qSmfadlMXHiTcbdzoS+LQ agent
debug1: Server accepts key: xxxx@r-23-105-25-172.comp.xxxx.edu.sg RSA SHA256:01e48aRr8gQiUtaLrKj5O9qSmfadlMXHiTcbdzoS+LQ agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to xxxx.xxxx.edu.sg ([xxxx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL_VERSION = 3.4.12
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL = iTerm2
```

I am unable to figure out where is this public key `Will attempt key: xxxx@r-23-105-25-172.comp.xxxx.edu.sg RSA SHA256:01e48aRr8gQiUtaLrKj5O9qSmfadlMXHiTcbdzoS+LQ agent` present on my local machine?

Comment: "... agent" -> Your key seems to be in a key-agent

Comment: The key is located in */Users/xxxx/.ssh/*

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how ssh / public key encryption works.  You can't use public key auth without being in pisession of the corresponding private key.